# Why will my javascript embedded in my HTML to randomize a list not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to create a very beginner script that would choose a random word from a list of topics, in order to do this I've created an html page that I believe correctly embeds the javascript that I've mainly copied off of stackoverflow , but something isn't working correctly. My html button that should be generating a random word will do nothing. Below is html code, as well as the javascript code. I'm very new at this, please feel free to inform me on how to better word these questions, or of anything I've done wrong. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>isportal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href
</head>
<body>
<h1>Completely Neccessary Generator </h1>
<div id="quoteDisplay">
    <!--Quotes will display here -->
</div>
<button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="randomItem.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code is

```
var myArray = [
"Administrative",
"Fiber Optic",
"BIOS",
"Security",
"Firewall",
"Mainframe",
"Power-cycling",
"HTML",
"Server-side",
"Coding-based",
"Power-orientied",
"Server",
"Connection-based",
"Networking"
];
function newQuote()  {
var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

Random.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
}
```

Expected results is the javascript will generate a random word based off of the array, actual results is that nothing is generated.

Comment: `document.body.innerHtml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like the random item to show in the div with id of 'quoteDisplay'

```
function newQuote()  {
    var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = randomItem;
}
```

Comment: This was the solution, thanks a ton! I had originally copied some code off of another website, and whenever i saw document.getElementbyID i assumed that I was supposed to change that from a generic document to the document's name. That's where I was mistaken! Thanks for the answer I really appreciate the help!

Comment: glad I was able to help. please mark this answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Random.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
```

Try

```
document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = randomItem;
```

This code will fetch the div with ID `quoteDisplay` and set its HTML to that of `randomItem`.

In the code that you have provided `Random` is not defined and hence your code does not work. If you check the console, you should be getting a console error.